# Polymer error when template is auto binding

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to use `core-list` extension from polymer.
I used example from Google Developers from [This YT Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UKPRbrw3Kk)

I add `is="auto-binding"` value to my template i go error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of null
```

I'm also trying to set `height: 100%` to `core-list` , it's also not working , I got warning:

```
core-list must either be sized or be inside an overflow:auto div that is sized
```

Below I'm adding my code:

```
    <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-list/core-list.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-pages/core-pages.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<!--{{hash}-->
<polymer-element name="progress-page" attributes="hash">
    <template>
                    <template is="auto-binding" id="app" style=" height:100%; overflow: auto;">
                        <core-list data="{{data}}" flex style=" height:100%;">
                            <template>
                                <div class="row" layout horizontal center>
                                    <div data-index="{{index}}">{{model.name}}</div>
                                </div>
                            </template>
                        </core-list>
                    </template>

</template>

    <script>
        Polymer('progress-page', {
            ready: function () {
                this.selected = 0;
                var app = document.querySelector('#app');
                app.data = generateContacts();

                function generateContacts() {
                    var data = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            name: 'dddd',
                            string: 'asd'
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            }
        });

    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Cam somebody please tell me what's wrong ? This is 1:1 version from link I've added.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `template is="auto-binding"` *inside* a Polymer element. The whole point of an autobinding template is that it allows you to set up data binding *outside* a Polymer element.

So you're combining two concepts here. These two lines are what you'd use if you were using an auto-binding template in your main page:

```
var app = document.querySelector('#app');
app.data = generateContacts();
```

Here you're trying to retrieve a reference to the auto-binding template and add a data property to it.

This won't work in your context. '#app' is inside `<progress-page>`'s shadow DOM, so `document.querySelector` won't find it.

This line, on the other hand, is adding a property to the `<progress-page>` element, which is the proper thing to do if you're using core-list inside an element:

```
this.selected = 0;
```

So if you want to use an auto-binding template, eliminate the Polymer element and use the first approach (querySelector and assign app.data, app.selected).

If you want to create a Polymer element, eliminate the auto-binding template and use the second approach:

```
this.data = generateContacts();
this.selected = 0;
```

Here's a working version of this code with the auto-binding template removed:

http://jsbin.com/lofega/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for reply, but can you tell me how to put core-list into paper-tabs ? When I'm trying to put core-list into paper tabs I still got error " core-list must either be sized or be inside an overflow:auto div that is sized"

Comment: Are you trying to put the `core-list` _inside_ `paper-tabs`? Or control it with `paper-tabs`?

`paper-tabs` is just a tabstrip. If you want to change views based on the currently selected tab, you want something like `core-pages` or `core-animated-pages`. Take a look at the [single-page app article](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/spa.html ) (which uses `core-animated-pages` and a menu) and see if that helps. Same general approach for tabs (put the tabs in the toolbar, and use data binding to connect the tabs and the `core-pages` control.

Comment: As you said I'm trying to use 'paper-tabs' with 'core-animated-pages' , now i'm having trouble with pages transitions and urls.

Comment: Now I'm using core-animated pages with core list and I'm still having error with core-list height.